# MAMP PRO localhost waiting and waiting

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

My setting :

- OSX : 10.10.3
- Mamp Pro : 3.2.1
- MODX : 2.3.3
- MySql : 5.5.42
- PHP : 5.6.7
- Apache HTTP port : 8888
- Apache HTTPS port : 8890
- MySql port : 8889

I have OSX 10.10 installed since october 2014, and I upgrade to 10.10.3 in April 2015.

I use MAMP Pro for local development with MODX fo many years. I have more than 20 sites under Mamp Pro. Since today (2015-06-09) I had never had any problems.

Now, It take more than 5 minutes to log to MODX manager, but I have no problem at all to see the front end of my local websites.

And when I am logged, it take several seconds (more than 10) to display any pages in the manager.

I have access to PHPmy Admin with no problem.

- Clearing the MODX core/cache and clearing the browser cache did not change anything.
- The error log (Apache, MySql, PHP, DDNS ) of MAMP and Modx error log, indicates no error.

My host file (with not all virtual host)

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   bulles.dev  # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
::1     bulles.dev  # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
127.0.0.1   simo.dev    # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
::1     simo.dev    # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
```

Does anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

Thank you for your help.